# Can I have 2 separate Active Directory Forests with the same domain extension?

Tags: active-directory

I need to configure two AD forests with a trust between them. The customer wants to use the naming "forest1.domain.com" and "forest2.domain.com". Note that these are not separate domains in a forest but rather separate forests.

Can their names both end in domain.com? They only own domain.com in public DNS and want their internal AD domain names to use that extension as recommended here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc772970%28v%3dws.10%29.

Comment: I think it is easily possible, as the forests have distinct names! For the naming convention of forests, it doesn't matter - till you've different names.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.